# missing 1 required positional argument error, not sure on this one

Tags: python, attributes

```
RIGHT = 1
LEFT = -1
FORWARD = 1
REVERSE = 0

class exercise:

    def __init__(self):
        self.speed = 0
        self.direction = 0
        self.simulation = []
        self.simulation_loaded = False
        self.direction_change = 0
        
    def accelerate(self):

        print("accelerating")

    def turn_left(self, direction_change):
       
        print("turning left")
        direction_change += direction_change
        print(direction_change)
        
    def turn_right(self, direction_change):
        
        print("turning right")
        direction_change -= direction_change
        print(direction_change)


    def load_simulation(self, filename):
       
        with open('simulation.txt', 'r') as command_file:
            for cmd in command_file:
                cmd = cmd.strip()
                exercise.commands_table[cmd](exercise())

        print(self.speed, self.direction,)

    commands_table = {'ACCELERATE':accelerate, 'FORWARD':accelerate, 'LEFT':turn_left, 'RIGHT':turn_right,}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_exercise  = exercise()
    my_exercise.load_simulation("simulation.txt")
```

This also has a txt file where it gets its commands from, the error im getting is, "turn_left() missing 1 required positional argument: 'direction_change'" this error occurs on line 41 being the "exercise.commands_tablecmd". Im really not sure on this and a hint would be really appreciated.

Comment: should be `exercise.commands_table[cmd](self, XXX)` where XXX is what you miss, like `direction_change` for turn_right and turn_left methods

Comment: Also you never change `self.direction_change` so I'm not sure you do understand what is a class and how to use it, you should learn on that

Comment: its not a completed program, thats why it doesn't seem to change at the moment, thanks for the help though

Comment: also whatever I put in for XXX says it isnt defined.. give me a minute with this lol

Comment: Well ok, but for now your turn* methods does just nothing

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand?

Comment: Both `direction_change` in `direction_change -= direction_change` are the SAME variable, you don't change the instance one which is `self.direction_change`

Comment: thanks for the help, gonna go back to the drawing board for a bit see if I can do what i need to do in a better way, thanks though